# Tracking member tagging of artists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I'm writing a web based jukebox for my own amusement and as a learning experiencing.

I'm finally getting around to finishing my models except for one big component: member genre tags. I know I'll have to relate three models and it'll involve using `association_proxy` and collection classes.

Here's the relevant models (I had an abstract model to handle declaring the id and name fields, but that caused issues that I'll look at later):

```
class Member(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'members'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(128))
    ##tagged_artists is a backref from MemberTaggedArtist
    tags = association_proxy('tagged_artists', 'artist',
                             creator=lambda k,v: MemberTaggedArtist(tag=k, artist=v)
                             )

class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(128))

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name', db.String(128))

class MemberTaggedArtist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'membertaggedartists'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    member_id = db.Column('member_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('members.id'))
    artist_id = db.Column('artist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'))
    tag_id    = db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))

    member = db.relationship(Member, backref=db.backref(
                             'tagged_artists',
                             collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('tag')
                             )
    artist = db.relationship(Artist, backref='applied_tags')
    tag    = db.relationship(Tag, backref='applied_artists')
```

What I'd *like* to happen is this:

```
>>> member = Member(name='justanr')
>>> artist = Artist(name='Gorguts')
>>> tag = Tag('Death Metal')
>>> member.tags['Death Metal'].append('Gorguts')
>>> member.tags
... {'Death Metal':['Gorguts']}
```

What *currently* happens is this (note, I built a mixin to handle repr calls):

```
>>> member.tags
... {Tag (ID:1 Name:Death Metal): MemberTaggedArtist (ID: 1 Member:justanr  Artist:Gorguts Tag:Death Metal)}
```

I haven't been working with `association_proxy` long enough to understand what I'm doing wrong and even the brief tutorial in the documentation is giving me issues (I'm not sure why and I don't think it's because I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy).

In short, I'm attempting to build an association proxy to create a dict of lists and I'm completely lost. I'm unsure what values I should proxy along, if using one middle table is over complicating this, and how to construct a secondary (and possibly tertiary) middle table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution. I forgot what I knew about SQL...lol I guess? But I recently watched several talks on SQLA that made me realize that I had an 'O' problem -- I was focusing specifically on the Object portion of ORM instead of thinking "SQLA just makes writing Queries easier, it doesn't do it for me." It also didn't help that FSQLA's query object lulled me in complacency either. Don't get me wrong, it's fantastic for basic queries and joins, but for something this complex...not really.

I also didn't realize that my question was actually several questions. One part was "How do I write this query with SQLA's tools?" The other was, "Help me puzzle the correct `association_proxy` to get this desired outcome."

I'm still not sure about the association proxy portion of it yet, or if I even want to do that anymore. But I finally puzzled the solution to my first question out:

```
# Query database for tag names and count for a particular artist
artist = models.Artist.find_by_some_means(magic, vars)
q = db.session.query(
    models.Tag.id.label('id'), 
    models.Tag.name.label('tag'), 
    db.func.count(models.MemberTaggedArtist.member_id).label('count')
    )

q = q.join(models.MemberTaggedArtist, models.Tag.id == models.MemberTaggedArtist.tag_id)
q = q.filter(models.MemberTaggedArtist.artist_id == artist.id)
q = q.group_by(models.MemberTaggedArtist.tag_id)
# order by tag count first, then tag name if two tags happen to have the same count
# there's probably a much better way to get there without recalculating the result
q = q.order_by(db.desc(db.func.count(models.MemberTaggedArtist.member_id)))
q = q.order_by(models.Tag.name)
```

My original planned query was something along the lines of:

```
SELECT tags.name AS tag,  tags.id AS id, count(mta.member_id) AS count
FROM tags, membertaggedartists AS mta
WHERE tags.id = mta.tag_id AND mta.artist_id = :artist_id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY count DESC, name ASC
```

And SQLA interprets my request as:

```
SELECT tags.id AS id, tags.name AS tag, count(membertaggedartists.member_id) AS count
FROM tags 
JOIN membertaggedartists ON tags.id = membertaggedartists.tag_id
WHERE membertaggedartists.artist_id = :artist_id_1 
GROUP BY membertaggedartists.tag_id 
ORDER BY count(membertaggedartists.member_id) DESC, tags.name
```

Which is remarkably similar (and uses an explicit join unlike mine, which negates the need for one of my original WHERE clauses).